# Reportviewer not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional and vb.net.    When I start a new Windows Form and drag ReportViewer to the blank form, it does not appear on the form. At the bottom, it shows ReportViewer1; however, there is no reportviewer visible. This means I can't attach the viewer to a report or database.

If I start an entirely new project, I can drag the reportVierwer.   This is a big project or I would just start a new one and do it.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason (on VS2015) the ReportViewer instance is not added to the Controls collection of the form inside the InitializeComponents method.

Adding this line (reportViewer being the instance of ReportViewer) fixes the problem:

```
this.Controls.Add(reportViewer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add it in code behind manually, or to manually edit the designer.

Add the Load event handler to the form to refresh the report viewer on Load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

And in designer create the `ReportViewer` instance. In `InitializeComponent`:

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.ReportViewer1 = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer()

    '...

    '
    'ReportViewer1
    '
    Me.ReportViewer1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
    Me.ReportViewer1.Name = "ReportViewer1"
    Me.ReportViewer1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(396, 246)
    Me.ReportViewer1.TabIndex = 0

    '...
End Sub
Friend WithEvents ReportViewer1 As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer
```

It's not ideal solution. When adding to your main code you are mixing presentation and logic. When modifying designer code there is a risk it will be overridden.

Perhaps some improvement would be to create yet another Form partial class where you put the above mentioned code. For instance, as `LoadReportViewer` method and then invoke the method from your code. This way you do not mingle designer code with logic and you don't risk the change is removed by designer.

Comment: I added all of this code and it took it without giving an error.   However, on the Design view, I can't see the Report Viewer.   I assume there is a setting that isn't correct or a reference that is off.    It would be best if I can find that.   By the way, this code is the same that is there when I add Report Viewer from the toolbox, except for the ReportViewer1.Refresh Report.     When added from the toolbox, ReportViewer1 is in the Properties window.

Comment: I created a report in a new program and copied it over to this project's folder and added it and the report viewer is visible.   Don't know if this hint will help anyone help me figure it out, but this is what is happening.

Comment: What's the difference in the designer generated code? Perhaps that will give some clue what was missing in the original solution.